# callback foreach mongodb nodejs

Tags: arrays, mongodb, asynchronous

I have a problem, I have created a function in nodejs that returns all the values of the mongodb query inside it which is wrapped around async.forEach. Now when I do the mongodb query, it only returns one result, from the first value of the array, the rest doesnt get executed. I want my code to query all the values in the array and give me all the result in one callback. Please Help.

```
  function folderE (ab, cb) {

  var fi = [546545454587, 89798784564, q4q5q45q4]


async.forEach(fi, (fold, bn) => {


     dbo.collection(folderCollection).find( {folderID: fold } ).toArray( (err, folderData) => {
  if (err) throw err;

      bn(folderData)

     }) //findone 

 }, function (result) {

    ab(result)

     })
```

Comment: `forEach()` does not return a result. You want [`map()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map). Also that really should be `.find( {folderID: fold } ).toArray(bn)` and allow the possible errors to "trickle down" through the function instead of explicitly throwing. The final should also be `function(err,result)` and not `function(result)` as you have, as again the first argument is an "error" as per node callback style.

Comment: I tried map, same result, only getting one value

Comment: Read the full comment. You're doing various things wrong.